# Finding duplicates in C

Tags: c, arrays, list

I'm trying to write a code that checks whether or not a list has duplicates in it. I start with a table of a certain (variable) number of elements (=size). So far so good, no bugs or errors. Then I make the program execute this:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    while ((i + j) < size) {
        j = 1;
        if (table[i] == table[i + j])
            printf("Duplicate: %d", table[i]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

After I compile this and run the program, it just continues scanning until infinity. Could somebody help me find the error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are setting `j=1` at every iteration. Move it outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: the way to know is using a [debugger](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error being found in other answers, the proper way to do it is:

```
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1; j<size; j++) // <~~
        {
            if (table[i]==table[j])
                printf("Duplicate: %d",table[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You set `j` inside your j `while` loop. Every time it runs, `j = 1`, so `i + j` never exceeds`size`

Answer (score 0):

This line is not at the correct place:

```
 j=1;
```